# Write a set of prolog rules that returns a list which contains the larger item in each position in two lists of the same length?

Tags: prolog

Very, VERY new to Prolog here.  My function needs to compare two lists of equal length by taking the larger number into a new list (e.g. `larger([3, 12, 5], [6, 3, 11], X)` returns `X =  [6, 12, 11].`)  This is what I have, but it is not getting me what I need:

```
larger([],[],[]).
larger([H|T],[E|A],X):- H > E, larger([T],[A],[H|X]).
larger([H|T],[E|A],X):- H < E, larger([T],[A],[E|X]).
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is OK, this is a slightly different approach.

Two clauses should be enough:

```
larger([], [], []).
larger([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :-
    /* Z is the larger number from (X, Y) */
    larger(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

How you do the part in the comments depends on your exact problem statement and maybe the implementation. At least SWI-Prolog and GNU-Prolog both have an *arithmetic function* `max()` that you can use like this in the above:

```
larger([], [], []).
larger([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :-
    Z is max(X, Y),
    larger(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

This is arguably nicer than the solution with three clauses because it won't leave behind unnecessary choice points. Like the other solution, it will work fine as long as the two lists have numbers in them.

This would be identical to using a `maplist`, for example like this:

```
larger(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
    maplist(max_number, Xs, Ys, Zs).

max_number(X, Y, Z) :- Z is max(X, Y).
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not far.

Try with

```
larger([], [], []).

larger([H | T], [E | A], [H | X]) :-
  H > E,
  larger(T, A, X).

larger([H | T], [E | A], [E | X]) :-
  H =< E,
  larger(T, A, X).
```

If I'm not wrong, there are three errors in your code.

(1) you have to translate the bigger head value (`H` or `E`) in the third argument of `larger/3`, not in the recursive call

```
% ------- H added here ---v
larger([H | T], [E | A], [H | X]) :-
  H > E,
  larger(T, A, X).
% not here ----^
```

(2) `T` and `A`, the tails in `[H|T]` and `[E|A]`, are lists, so you have to pass they recursively as `T` and `A`, not as `[T]` and `[A]`

```
larger([H | T], [E | A], [H | X]) :-
  H > E,
  larger(T, A, X).
% not larger([T], [A], X)
```

(3) if you have the cases `H > E` and `H < E`, your code fail when `H` is equal to `E`; one solution is `H > E` and `H =< E`; the secon case cover `H` equal to `E`.